# UILabel text as tags and hyperlink

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a string which I am getting from the server and is dynamic. It is of the format:

```
<p> <a href="/users/user32" class="mentions mentions-32" title="John Appleseed">John Appleseed</a> Hey <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> </p>
```

Couple of related questions I want to ask in one thread

1. I want to make the mention text and the URL text to appear in bold and different colour
2. When URL is tapped it should open a the link in WebView
3. When the mention text is tapped, it should perform some other action (open User Profile VC)
4. When tapping mention text, it should send a parameter (`uid`) to the method, the uid can be extracted from `mentions-32` (32 is uid here)

This string can have multiple mentions and links. I am stripping off the HTML tags and I get plain text. I know there is library [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which can be used here

Note: This functionality can be compared to what facebook or twitter app does on Newsfeed post text. (Tapping on tag takes the user to User Profile and tapping on the hyperlink opens a webview)

Comment: Is there anything that TTTAttributedLabel doesn't support?

Answer (score 0):

I think the better option to use the GLTapLabel GitHub Demo it is useful for the custom UILabel view controller for iOS that works just like a regular UILabel.

Hope this Demo is helpful u.